# Studying mathematics in France (universities and grandes ecoles)

Tags: soft-question

I am currently a senior in Albania and would like to study mathematics in France. However, I'm not quite sure if the universities or the so-called "grandes ecoles" provide the best quality of mathematics programs and how exactly are their programs different. 
I was thinking about applying to both since I've not made up my mind yet. Can someone please list the best universities in France for a BS in mathematics and the best "classes preparatoires scientifiques"?
If I decide to go to a university, what exactly are some future career possibilities with a BS in mathematics? Is there, for example, any chance that in the third year I specialize in computer science too? Or is it better to get a master in cs or something like that.

I would really appreciate anyone who could answer any of my questions. :)
Thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

France is a power house in math for sure, and you made the right move. I think you just need to find out what your specialty is and which universities has the best professors that concentrate in your area, and apply there. The French system has a very high level of math at universities, and they are popular in areas like: number theory, algebraic geometry, analysis, and differential equations. To name a few:

-Univ of Rouen.
-Paris 11.
-Univ of Marie Curie.
-Univ of Grenoble.
-Ecole Polytechnique.